# What exactly is this regular expression doing?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking over some code and found the following regex:

```
var querystring = querystring.replace(/[^&]+=\.?(?:&|$)/g, '')
```

Is this taking the querystring and replacing all values that begin with an ampersand or question mark with a space? Is there more going on here that I don't see?

You're logical explanation is much appreciated and help gain a little more understanding of regex. Thanks!

Comment: This removes all strings that matches /[^&]+=\.?(?:&|$)/g (the second argument is an empty string not a space) that's all it does.

Comment: Why is querystring being searched/replaced upon and defined on the same line?

Comment: It's on a form processing script, the querystring was serialized before the line I posted above: `var querystring = $(this).serialize();` I should have said that.

Comment: Matches `abc=.&` , `a=` (assuming last match), `===` (assuming last match), and `____=.` , but not `&abc=.`, `=` or `abc=.&` (assuming last match).

Comment: @Neil So it seems it's cleaning up empty values from the form it's processing, does that sound about right?

Comment: @BD_Design, yes, it would appear that it's removing anomalous parameters.  Not sure how successful it is at doing it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears to remove those parameters from the query string whose value is:

1. empty
2. equal to `.`

For example:

```
"remove1=&remove2=.&keep1=..&keep2=a&keep3=b".replace(/[^&]+=\.?(?:&|$)/g, '')
// returns "keep1=..&keep2=a&keep3=b"
```

Comment: I see, it's cleaning up empty values from the string. Excellent reply, much appreciated! Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

`[^&]+` one or more non "&" characters

`=` a literal "=" character

`\.?` an optional "."

`(?:&|$)` a "&" character or the end of the string

Would e.g. match

> Foobar=.&
>   A=